# Show coupon code only to fans of my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

As an author, I've created a Facebook page for my pseudonym. I also have a coupon code for a free eBook that I'd like to distribute as an incentive to like my page.

How can I ensure that the code only shows up when you like the page? I don't necessarily need a whole landing page, but it should be easily found.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can imagine is by creating a Facebook application like one of these:

A custom tab

https://www.socialtools.me/custom-tab-on-facebook

A promotional coupon

https://www.socialtools.me/promotional-coupon-on-facebook

These are free for use the first time, and if you don't have a lot of fans (< 300), are always free.

Remember to activate the fangate option when configuring the app.